# Add file to existing table from ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net-mvc

I am just trying to learn ASP.NET MVC and am having an issue, well not so much of an issue but lack of understanding any is not working I am trying to update an SQL table, the code below works fine if I want to delete a table but all I want to do is to add another file to the data table

```
public async Task<IActionResult> DeleteSnTFileFromFileSystem(int id)
{
    var file = await context.SnTModels.Where(x => x.Id == id).FirstOrDefaultAsync();

    if (file == null) 
        return null;

    var basePath = Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() + "\\wwwroot" + file.FilePath);

    if (System.IO.File.Exists(basePath))
    {
        System.IO.File.Delete(basePath);
    }

    context.SnTModels.Remove(file);

    context.SaveChanges();

    TempData["Message"] = $"Removed {file.Name + file.Extension} successfully from File System.";
    return RedirectToAction("Scenario");
}
```

Here is my code to create the table

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<IActionResult> SnTUploadToFileSystem(List<IFormFile> files, string description)
{
    foreach (var file in files)
    {
        var subPath = "\\*dir file\\";
        var basePath = Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() + "\\wwwroot" + subPath);

        bool basePathExists = System.IO.Directory.Exists(basePath);

        if (!basePathExists) 
            Directory.CreateDirectory(basePath);

        var fileName = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(file.FileName);
        var filePath = Path.Combine(basePath, file.FileName);
        var extension = Path.GetExtension(file.FileName);

        if (!System.IO.File.Exists(filePath))
        {
            // saving our file to the file system
            using (var stream = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Create))
            {
                await file.CopyToAsync(stream);
            }

            // creating a model and save this model into the db
            var SnTModel = new SnTOnFileSystem
                {
                    CreatedOn = DateTime.UtcNow,
                    FileType = file.ContentType,
                    Extension = extension,
                    Name = fileName,
                    Description = description,
                    FilePath = subPath + file.FileName
                };

            context.SnTModels.Add(SnTModel);
            context.SaveChanges();
        }
    }

    TempData["Message"] = "File successfully uploaded to File System.";

    return RedirectToAction("Index");
}
```

Here is the post to update the table

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<IActionResult> SnTUpdateToFileSystem(List<IFormFile> files, int id)
{
    var file = files[0];
    var subPath = "\\Training\\SnT\\Document\\";

    var basePath = Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() + "\\wwwroot" + subPath);

    bool basePathExists = System.IO.Directory.Exists(basePath);

    if (!basePathExists) 
        Directory.CreateDirectory(basePath);

    var fileName = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(file.FileName);
    var documentFilePath = Path.Combine(basePath, file.FileName);
    var extension = Path.GetExtension(file.FileName);

    if (!System.IO.File.Exists(documentFilePath))
    {
        // saving our file to the file system
        using (var stream = new FileStream(documentFilePath, FileMode.OpenOrCreate))
        {
            await file.CopyToAsync(stream);
        }

        // creating a model and save this model into the db
        var SnTModel = new SnTOnFileSystem
            {
                Name = fileName,
                DocumentFilePath = subPath + file.FileName
            };

        context.SnTModels.Update(SnTModel);
        context.SaveChanges();
    }

    TempData["Message"] = "Document successfully uploaded to File System.";
    return RedirectToAction("Scenario");
}
```

Comment: What are you expecting to see vs what are you seeing?

Comment: I want to post a second file under same ID but into column documentFilePath in SQL table